# Converting a string variable to binary while having missing values

Tags: if-statement, stata, dummy-variable

I'm having trouble converting a string variable regarding depression to a binary one.

I currently have a variable in my data set called `dp1` which indicates whether an individual responded "yes", "no", or "don't know" on a questionnaire. I'm trying to generate a binary variable  from this where yes=1, no=0 and don't know=missing.

Comment: If you want explanation of why code you tried didn't work you need to tell us what the code it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this. As you should want informative text for your variable to show in graphs and tables, the best approach is possibly something like this using `encode`:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str10 dp1
"yes"       
"no"        
"don't know"
end

label def dp1 0 "no" 1 "yes" .a "don't know"

encode dp1, gen(wanted) label(dp1)

list 

     +-------------------------+
     |        dp1       wanted |
     |-------------------------|
  1. |        yes          yes |
  2. |         no           no |
  3. | don't know   don't know |
     +-------------------------+

list, nolabel

     +---------------------+
     |        dp1   wanted |
     |---------------------|
  1. |        yes        1 |
  2. |         no        0 |
  3. | don't know       .a |
     +---------------------+
```